Any idea how much it costs to send 100000 sms via aws SNS?
I currently studying a little but about AWS and i had a question, I couldn't find the price of sms in the SNS price list, would anyone have any idea what the average would be for 100,000 sms/month

SNS SMS has a special pricing page, that is linked to at the bottom of the SNS service's pricing page: https://aws.amazon.com/sns/sms-pricing/

Also note that you start using Amazon SNS you will be in an SMS sandbox - Amazon Simple Notification Service and then you will need to apply to Move out of the SMS sandbox - Amazon Simple Notification Service.
